# how to display percentage instead of count in bar plot using AWS QuickSight

Tags: bar-chart, percentage, amazon-quicksight

I am plotting a simple bar plot. Instead of displaying the count of records for each category which is the default setting in Quicksight, I want to display the % of records in each category.

How can that be done in QuickSight ?

For example, in the below diagram, the category "A" has 608 out of total 1985 records (608+294+803+280) which is 31%.

Hence in the below chart, i want it to be displayed as 31%, 15%, 40% and 14% instead of the current values 608, 294, 803 and 280

Please advise.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vMrF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a calculated field using percentoftotal and then graph that field.

Here is some additional information:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/percentOfTotal-function.html